# CodeKit 2 Compile error when trying compile SASS file for Omega 4 Drupal Site

Tags: ruby, drupal, drupal-7, sass, codekit

I'm new to SASS and CodeKit and am trying to compile a SASS file. The project is a Drupal Omega 4 subtheme. I'm running Mac OSX 10.10 with all the Ruby Gems installed and I'm trying to figure out where the hangup is that's not letting CodeKit compile the file. Any ideas would be much appreciated This is the error I get:

> ArgumentError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'
>       Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

**This is the config.rb file**

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require '~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/'
# require '~/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/'

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = ""
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"

output_style = :nested

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false
color_output = false
```

**This is the SCSS file I'm trying to compile**

```
// Import external libraries.
@import "compass";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "singularitygs";
@import "toolkit";

// Import variables, abstractions, base styles and components using globbing.
//
// Globbing will always import files alphabetically. Optimally, all your
// components should be self-contained and explicit enough to not have any
// contained styles leak into unrelated components: The import order should not
// affect the result.
//
// If there are variables, functions or mixins that depend on each other and
// therefore need to be imported in a specific order you can import them
// directly. Variables-, function- or mixin providing partials should never
// output any styles themselves: Importing them multiple times to resolve
// dependencies shouldn't be a problem.
@import "variables/**/*";
@import "abstractions/**/*";
@import "base/**/*";
@import "components/**/*";
```

Comment: New error after setting HOME environment variable.    LoadError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Answer (score 1):

Try set the `HOME` environment variable in your `config.rb` file.

```
ENV['HOME'] = "/Users/YOUR_OS_USER_NAME"
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. I inserted that code with my username in place. I got a different error this time. Does this error code provide insight?